# How to find whether the ip address is proxy/vpn/vps

Tags: proxy, vpn, vps

I have a hosted web application, I would like to prevent signup from **proxy/VPN/VPS** ip address. How do i check whether the users ip address is proxy/vpn/vps syste.
For example **clixsense.com** site, users can't create account, it shows cannot access from proxy/vpn/vps ip address.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clixsense is blocking all amazon ec2 instances (VPC)

Answer (score -1):

Clixsense.com may pay someone who knows that certain sites are proxy/vpn/vps sites and are then able to block those sites. Short of that, there is nothing special about an IP address that would tell you that one is a proxy address vs. an actual endpoint address.

For example, network address translation (NAT) is a common form of "proxying". Your typical cable/DSL router makes it possible  for more than one person to connect to the internet from your house. You're all sharing the same ISP IP address. The router stores a table of IP address to port numbers that it uses to establish outgoing communications. When a reply from the internet is received, the router performs a lookup and routes the traffic appropriately. From the viewpoint of the server on the internet, it came from that one single IP address that your router is "connected" to from your house, even though your computer has one IP address and your spouse's computer has a different IP address.

HTH.